# Conditional tooltip for DataGridTextColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am currently facing a small issue with my DataGridTextColumn.

I want to display a tooltip at a DataGridTextColumn but only if the text is not empty.

How can I achieve this? The code that I am currently using:

```
                <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Person" Binding="{Binding SomeBinding, TargetNullValue='-'}" Width="Auto"
                CellStyle="{StaticResource SomeStyle}"/>
```

With the style

```
            <Style x:Key="SomeStyle" 
           TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource InactiveStyle}">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=SomeBinding}"/>
        </Style.Setters>
            </Style>
```

This code does provide me the tooltip, however, it is also showing the tooltip when there is no text. If there are any questions, please let me know and I can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add data triggers for `string.Empty` and `null`:

```
<Style x:Key="SomeStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource InactiveStyle}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SomeBinding}" Value="">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SomeBinding}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=SomeBinding}"/>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach :

```
    //Create a class which inherits from IValueConverter
    public class CellToolTipConverter : IValueConverter
    {
     #region IValueConverter Membres

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string stringValue = (string)value;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue))
            return  "Your tooltip";//As you are in a c# class, you have many possibilities.
       else
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
   }



     //In your xaml :

     //Declare your namespace
     xmlns:CustomClasses="clr-namespace:YourAssamblyName.YourNameSpaceOfConverterClass"


     <UserControl.Resources>
         <CustomClasses:CellToolTipConverter x:Key="CustomToolTipConverter"/>              
     </UserControl.Resources>



        //In your grid view
        <GridView.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewRow}">
                <Setter Property="MyCustomToolTipProperty" Value="{Binding YourProperty, Converter= 
     {StaticResource CustomToolTipConverter}}"/>
            </Style>
        </GridView.RowStyle>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am currently using the answer from mm8.

Comment: No, problem, I agree, it can be a better solution, I will keep the mine in case you or another person needs. Because the converter class is really flexible.